# Can a Shroud of Protection/Revival be removed by anyone?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items

> When you place the shroud of protection over an adjacent dying creature, [effect]. This effect lasts until the creature regains consciousness or dies, or until the shroud is removed (a standard action), whichever comes first.

<sup>Shroud of Protection/Revival, Adventurer's vault pg.177</sup>

Usually magic items need to indicate which parts interact with allies or enemies. However, it seems just too logical that everyone should be able to remove it with a standard action - thereby severely limiting it's usefulness.

Can the item be removed by someone who didn't activate the effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Anyone can remove the shroud.**

The text just says, "until the shroud is removed (a standard action)". It doesn't place any limitations on who can remove the shroud, so there aren't any.

Keep in mind that this doesn't actually limit its usefulness all that much. From a tactical perspective, it's usually a *much* better choice for enemies to try to take out the remaining characters who are conscious (especially healers) than to waste their turn removing the shroud from someone who isn't currently a threat.